# Is it possible for the same file to exist in more than one directory?

Tags: linux, windows, filesystems

Just a simple question, borne out of learning about File Systems;

Is it possible for a single file two simultaneously exist in two or more directories?

I'd like to know if this is possible in Linux and well as Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with either hard- or soft links (and maybe on Windows with shortcuts. I'm not sure about that). Note this is different from making a *copy* of the file! In both cases, you only store the same file **once**, unlike when you make a copy.

In the case of hard links, the same file (on disk) will be referenced in two different places. You cannot distinguish between the 'original' and the 'new one'. If you delete one of them, the other will be unaffected; a file will only actually be deleted when the last "reference" is removed. An important detail is that the way hard links work means that you cannot create them for directories.

Soft links, also referred to as symbolic links, are a bit similar to shortcuts in Windows, but on a lower level.  if you open them for read or write operations, you'll read from the file, but you can distinguish between reading from the file directly, and reading from the soft link.

In Windows, the use of soft links is fairly uncommon, but there is support for it (IDK about the filesystem APIs, but there's a tool called `ln` just like on Unix).

Comment: Note that in Windows, soft links are usually called symbolic links.  There's also a third sort called junctions, but they are only for directories.